Scaling Advanced Marker created with custom HTML on click
I try to switch from Legacy Markers to Advanced Markers, and one functionality I need is to scale the marker when it was clicked (and rescale when it has no focus).
So I create a custom marker, e.g., like this:
const markerHtml = document.createElement('div');
markerHtml.className = 'marker-container';
markerHtml.innerHTML = `<img class="marker-container-img" src="${url}"/>`;

const googleMarker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
            ...
            content: markerHtml,
            ...
          });

Everything is fine, but how can I change/access the class on my HTML or change the size of the marker in the onClick Listener?
Alternative: Can I somehow use a Pinelement that uses a custom svg for the whole marker and not just the glyph where I can also set a label text on the marker?

Yes you can. The marker needs to be clickable (gmpClickable) and you can use addListener() on the marker for the click event, and addEventListener() on the marker content (that is your HTML element) for the mouseleave or whatever event fits your needs. The AdvancedMarkerElement class currently only supports click and drag/dragstart/dragend events.
Here is an example with a SVG but the same would work with any HTML element. You just need to target the right element in the event listeners.


async function initMap() {

  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const center = {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  }
  
  // Create map
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 4,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });

  // Marker SVG
  const svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 12 12" enable-background="new 0 0 12 12" id="Слой_1" version="1.1" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M6,0C3.2385864,0,1,2.2385864,1,5s2.5,5,5,7c2.5-2,5-4.2385864,5-7S8.7614136,0,6,0z M6,7  C4.8954468,7,4,6.1045532,4,5s0.8954468-2,2-2s2,0.8954468,2,2S7.1045532,7,6,7z" fill="#1D1D1B"/></svg>';
  
  // Create parser and SVG element
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const svgElement = parser.parseFromString(
    svg,
    "image/svg+xml",
  ).documentElement;

  // Add default classes
  svgElement.classList.add('red', 'pin');

  // Create AdvancedMarker
  let marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: center,
    content: svgElement,
    gmpClickable: true
  });
  
  // Click event listener
  marker.addListener('click', ({ domEvent, latLng }) => {
  
    const { target } = domEvent;
    
    target.parentElement.classList.remove('red');
    target.parentElement.classList.add('yellow', 'big');
  });
  
  // Mouseleave event listener
  marker.content.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {

    const { target } = event;
    
    target.classList.remove('yellow', 'big');
    target.classList.add('red')
  });
}

initMap();
#map {
  height: 150px;
}

.pin {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.big {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

svg.red path {
  fill: red;
}

svg.yellow path {
  fill: yellow;
}
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});</script>




Here's an example! https://jsfiddle.net/b4rk851w/2/
Listen to the click event and update the pinElement.
async function initMap() {
    // Request needed libraries.
    const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary(
        "marker",
    );
    const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 37.419, lng: -122.02 },
        zoom: 14,
        mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
    });
    const pinScaled = new PinElement({
        scale: 1.5,
    });
    const markerViewScaled = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
        map,
        position: { lat: 37.419, lng: -122.02 },
        content: pinScaled.element,
    });
    let clicked = false;
    markerViewScaled.addListener('click', () => {

        if (clicked) {
            // Change the colors of the PinElement on click
            pinScaled.background = '#11A1E1';
            pinScaled.borderColor = '#00609F'; // New border color
            pinScaled.glyphColor = '#00609F'; // New glyph (text) color
        } else {
            pinScaled.background = '#ff3333';
            pinScaled.borderColor = '#00609F'; // New border color
            pinScaled.glyphColor = '#00609F';
        }

        clicked = !clicked;


        // Reapply the updated PinElement to the marker content
        marker.content = pinGlyph.element;

    });

}

initMap();


